# Click on Div and More Specific Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that has a click() action that causes some animations on some other elements. That's all working well and good.

The problem is that there are some links within this div that have stopped working.

For example, here is a simplified example:

```
<div class="clickable-div">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:my_function();">
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.clickable-div').click(function() {
      ...
  });
});
```

What can I do to run my_function when that link is clicked?

Another consideration is that there is plain text and images within clickable-div. I would like to still trigger .clickable-div when those items are clicked.

Edit:

Another strange thing. There is a mailto link within this div. When I click the mailto link, my browser does the mailto action (opens a compose window in my mail client), but it also does .clickable-div.click. I would prefer that it doesn't do both.

Comment: Tip: Don't use inline JavaScript. Can you create a jsFiddle example illustrating the issue? What you've posted is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/J2jMV/

**CODE**

```
$('div.clickable-div').click(function() {
    alert("I'm not your function");
});
$('div.inner').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("I'm INNER!");
});
$("#clickme").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("Hello my function");   
});
```

have also a look here for event bubbling: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

hope it helps

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks for the `stopPropagation()` tip as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misreading the question, but it looks like you simply need to point to a different selector, also remove the `onclick=""`, and simply put that function within the jQuery click event handler.

Also, you want to separate JS from HTML (it's a best practice). Having onclick events also creates inline scripts in older browsers like IE8-- and can slow performance.

```
<div class="clickable-div">
    <a href="#">
</div>

$('div.clickable-div a').on('click', function () { 

   // do the things you already had here, only if there is no mailto
   if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('mailto') <= -1) {

       e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the mailto

       // now run your my_function animations
       my_function();
   }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on `onclick` actions.